# Does the factor theorem hold for Laurent Polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

For a field $\Bbbk$, $t\in \Bbbk$, and $p(x)\in \Bbbk[x^{\pm 1}]$ is it true that $p(t)=0$ implies that $p(x)=p'(x)(x-t)$ for some $p'(x)\in \Bbbk[x^{\pm 1}]$?

My first idea is just to take the valuation of $p(x)$ say $v$ and look at $p(x)*x^{-v}$ (assuming $v$ is negative). Then we apply the classic factor theorem to this product. Is this a reasonable idea or do I need some assumptions on $\Bbbk$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not make sense if $t=0$, since an "evaluation map" $\text{ev}_t:\mathbb{k}[x^{\pm 1}]\to\mathbb{k}$ given by $x\mapsto t$ can exist only if $t$ is a unit, ie if $t\in\mathbb{k}\setminus\{0\}$. (Why?) However, if indeed $t$ is non-zero, then the answer is yes. To see this, let $J$ be the ideal $\langle x-t\rangle$ of $\mathbb{k}[x^{\pm 1}]$. Since quotients commute with ring operations, and since $x\equiv_J t$ where $\equiv_J$ denotes equivalence modulo $J$, we have $p(x)\equiv_J p(t)=0$, ie $p(x)\in J$, ie $p(x)=(x-t)q(x)$ for some $q(x)\in\mathbb{k}[x^{\pm 1}]$, as desired.